# Trying to update MediaWiki categories, but it either lists wrong pages or none at all

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to add pages to various new categories on my Wiki, however it does not seem to be working at all. 
At the bottom of any given pages, say "Computer A" I want to be in category "Desktops"
So I add [[Category:Desktops]] to the bottom and go to Category:Desktops and nothing shows up.
I have another problem where "Computer B" Shows up in a category, despite no [[Category:XX]] being defined. 
What am I missing?

**Edit:**
SOLVED:

I navigated to my wiki/maintenance directory and ran rebuildall.php from my server shell. I didn't realize that these things don't update immediately.

Comment: They do, actually, unless you have misconfigured the [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue).

Comment: OK, so It wasn't entirely solved. I checked the job queue, set up a cron job, and manually ran runJobs.php but there are still several pages of mine with a template that has a category attached, and only 2 of the 10 articles I need in that category are in that category, and ShowJobQueue shows no jobs queued.

Comment: Ok, so I have a template, that has a category [[Category:Articles Under Construction]]

I add this template to 10 pages. Of those 10 pages, only 2 show up in the category, and only those two have "Articles Under Construction" in the category box. Even after running runJobs, RebuildLinks and RebuildAll, the pages DO NOT UPDATE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I noticed that in the template I used (based off Wikipedia's Good Article Template)  it had 
    `| maincat      = [[Category:Articles Under Construction]] `

Inside the `{{Top icon}}` function. If I removed that, and simply added the category code after the `}}` it works but included the template in the category as well.

Comment: Probably `maincat` means something like "only apply in the main namespace". You can use [`templates=expand`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php#Raw) to check whether the category is really there.